# How to filter all sections from an UITableView to get the wanted items

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have an `UITableView` populated by an array of objects (each object is a section). In this array of objects each object have few items (questions with description and other properties).
At the moment I hide from my `UITableView` all unwanted questions. But is not ok this practice so I want to refactor and to filter my questions to get only the required questions from each section.
So I want to have an array with sections where for each section the items was filtered.
The requirement is:

`item.showTrailer == false && item.showVehicle == true`.

Here is my code:

```
// MARK: MODEL
class ChecklistItemSection {

    var name: String // name of the section
    var checklistItems: [ChecklistItem] // all items from Checklist

    init(named: String, checklistItems: [ChecklistItem]) {

        self.name = named
        self.checklistItems = checklistItems
    }

    class func checklistItemSections() -> [ChecklistItemSection] {

        var allSections = [vehicleCheck(), viewingScreen() ]

        for (index, section) in allSections.enumerated() {
            if(section.checklistItems.count < 1) {
                allSections.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
        return allSections
    }

    // Private methods
    private class func vehicleCheck() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 3, poolID: 10, descript: "Tyres - Wear/Damage/Bulges/Cuts/Flat tyres", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 4, poolID: 22, descript: "Vehicle and trailer coupling: undamaged and safety locking device working", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: true, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 7, poolID: 20, descript: "Exhaust - Condition/Emission (Excess smoke)", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 3, poolID: 10, descript: "Tyres - Wear/Damage/Bulges/Cuts/Flat tyres", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 4, poolID: 22, descript: "Vehicle and trailer coupling: undamaged and safety locking device working", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: true, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 7, poolID: 20, descript: "Exhaust - Condition/Emission (Excess smoke)", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 1", checklistItems: checklistItems)
    }

    private class func viewingScreen() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 28, poolID: 16, descript: "Windscreen Wipers & Washers are they effective?", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 28, poolID: 16, descript: "Water Level - In cab indicator", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 2", checklistItems: checklistItems)
    }
}

class ChecklistItem{

    var showVehicle: Bool
    var showTrailer: Bool
}


// MARK: VC
class ChecklistViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var checklistItem: [ChecklistItemSection] = { return ChecklistItemSection.checklistItemSections() }()

    var filteredQuestions: [ChecklistItemSection] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filteredQuestions = All sections where the questions have showVehicle == true && showTrailer == false
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
filteredQuestions = checklistItem.filter { $0.checklistItems.filter { !$0.showTrailer && $0.showVehicle }.count != 0  }
```

---

**Edit:**

```
checklistItem.forEach {
    $0.checklistItems.forEach {
        if $0.showTrailer {
            $0.showTrailer = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can access the sections only like this, but I get error `Cannot convert value of type '[ChecklistItem]' to closure result type 'Bool'` when I type:
`        filteredQuestions = checklistItem.filter { $0.checklistItems.filter{$0.showVehicle == true && $0.showTrailer == false} } `

Comment: And how can I go through my original array and before to filter to say `if eachItem.showTrailer == true { eachItem.showTrailer = false }`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate your sections, with their checklist being filtered.

```
filteredQuestions = 
   checklistItem.map { ChecklistItemSection(named: $0.name, 
                                   checklistItems: $0.checklistItems.filter { $0.showVehicle 
                                                                        && !$0.showTrailer }) 
                     }
                // Add the next line if you want to remove sections without questions
                // .filter { $0.checkListItems.count > 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your array using following:

You will get filteredQuestions for every CheckListItem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            for item in checklistItem {
                filteredQuestions = item.filter{ $0.showTrailer == false && $0.showVehicle == true }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can access the sections only like this, but I get error `Cannot convert value of type '[ChecklistItem]' to closure result type 'Bool'` when I type:
`        filteredQuestions = checklistItem.filter { $0.checklistItems.filter{$0.showVehicle == true && $0.showTrailer == false} } `